# Creating Static Singleton Patterns in Java

Tags: java, javascript, scope, singleton

I'm creating a utility class which will be used (among other things) to create a new `org.mozilla.javascript.Context` object bound to the current thread. I have a single, global JavaScript scope which may have several import/initialization statements, etc.

I'd like for external classes to be able to retrieve a Context object and a Scope object for future execution by simply using `Utility.getContext()` and `Utility.getScope()`, without having to explicitly use the `getInstance()` function. The singleton pattern is necessary because both the context and scope need to be single instances.

Does the following code make sense?

```
public class Utility {
    private static Utility instance;
    private static ScriptableObject scope = null;

    private Utility() {}

    private static Utility getInstance() {
        synchronized (Utility.class) {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Utility();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private static Context getSingletonContext() {
        Context context = Context.getCurrentContext();
        if (context == null)
            context = Context.enter();
        if (scope == null) {
            scope = new ImporterTopLevel(context);
            Script script = context.compileString("Global JavaScript Here","Script Name",1,null);
            script.exec(context,scope);
            scope.sealObject();
        }
        return context;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getInstance().getSingletonContext();
    }

    public static Scriptable getScope() {
        Scriptable newScope = getContext().newObject(scope);
        newScope.setPrototype(scope);
        newScope.setParentScope(null);
        return newScope;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have locks on the context and scope singletons, so you have no guarantee those are going to be singletons.

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Java and JavaScript together? Java-ception.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** Make this public

```
public static Utility getInstance()
```

**2.** No need to make all the methods in the class static Except this `getInstance()` method.

**3.** When you try to access the singleton object of this class in other class do it this way.

```
Utility ut = Utility.getInstance();
```

See this is why you do NOT need to make the methods in Utility class static Except `getInstance()`

**4.** There are three way to get a **Singleton**,

**i.** synchronized method

**ii.** synchronized statement with Double check locking.

**iii.** Initializing the static Object Reference Variable at the Defining time..

**eg:**

**Initializing the static Object Reference Variable at the Defining time**

```
private static Utility instance = new Utility();

private Utility() {}

    private static Utility getInstance() {

           return instance;                  // WILL ALWAYS RETURN SINGLETON
                                      // REFER HEAD FIRST DESIGN PATTERN BOOK FOR DETAILS

    }
```

Comment: +1. And please, DO NOT use the [*"Double check locking"*](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Comment: @alfasin: Double-checked locking has worked since 1.5, as long as the instance field is made `volatile`.  That page you linked even says as much.

Comment: When referencing my class from other classes, I'd like to be able to call getContext and getScope directly, without having to call getInstance as well. Since these methods are completely independent on anything else in the application, the static definitions make more sense right?

Comment: cHao, true, but it's a bad practice (TMHO). Why not use the 3rd option which is the simplest and easiest to implement and understand ?

Comment: @user1533553: Static class or singleton; pick *one*.  You really don't need both; in fact, having instances that all modify the same shared state (but look separate) is going to bite you in the ass later.

Comment: @cHao: Isn't there only one instance, because of the singleton pattern? The static methods are there because they should be able to be used by external classes without having to call getInstance() first. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1533553: Yeah.  You're missing the fact that once you say `Utility.getContext()` and such all over your code, and instances have no state and no instance methods, it no longer matters whether there's one instance, or a billion, or *zero*.  You're not going to be able to easily use polymorphism, because static methods are tied to the type of the variable, not of the object.  So you've gone and made sure there's one instance that *has no reason to exist*.  Might as well just make everything static and get rid of the singletons.  Or keep the singletons and ditch the static methods. Pick one.

Comment: Ah interesting. So in that case, I would solve my problem simply by removing the static modifier on my scope ScriptableObject, right? Because then each instance (I say "each", but there would only ever be one or zero of them) would be storing state, namely the sealed scope object that is used to spawn new JavaScript scopes.

Comment: @user1533553: No, you wouldn't solve your problem -- you'd just create new ones.  Don't make it an instance field just to lawyer around the "if instances have no state" argument. You'll have artificially created a half-assed justification for the "singleton", but if you still access it all solely via static methods, you gain nothing but complexity by squirreling away a worthless instance. So make it all static and drop the singleton BS, or have real instances with instance methods and all that and drop the static BS.  (For reference, i'd drop both -- there's no real reason for either of them.)